# MapGuide open source : manipulating SDF data via java/jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, sdf, mapguide

I am relatively new to MapGuide open source technology. I would like to parse and modify data that is in SDF format so that my map displays this updated feature data (dynamically). How can i do so? I have MapGuide installed and configured on Linux. I went through the MapGuide Web API documentation but there were no examples on how to manipulate SDF data. Currently i am generating the SDF data in a different environment (in a Windows OS domain) by using scripts to query a spatial database and the query generates SHP files. I then transform those SHP files into SDF files (using scripts) before transferring them to the MapGuide server repository in the Linux OS environment. On the Windows OS end, I am able to edit the SHP files (in particular the dbf file just using a spread sheet) to change the values for the particular feature source. However this process is static and so i was hoping to be able to do so programmatically (using java / jsp) by parsing the SDF files for the particular feature source in the Linux domain. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay.. from what i have learnt elsewhere...The  SDF data cannot be edited directly using the Java Web API, instead Mapguide uses FDO which is an abstraction layer for accessing spatial data using a common api. [FDO on MapGuide Open Source](http://fdo.osgeo.org/)
Hope this helps anyone with a similar question to my original question.